# Inno Setup ignoring Registry Redirection?

Tags: windows, registry, 64-bit, inno-setup

I am running a setup on a 64-bit Windows 7 system. The script's (one that I've "inherited" and maintain these days) `[Setup]` section does not contain the `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode` directive.

Per the [docs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls):

- [Registry] writes to the 32-bit view by default.
- The Uninstall key is created in the 32-bit view of the registry.

This is my `[Registry]` section:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\{code:GetRegistryName}"; Flags: deletekey
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\{code:GetRegistryName}"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\{code:GetRegistryName}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "InstallPath"; ValueData: "{app}"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\{code:GetRegistryName}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "CurrentVersion"; ValueData: "{code:GetVersion}"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
```

...and yet, all of the keys land in the 64-bit part of the Registry - that is, nothing goes under `Wow6432Node`, as I would expect. Here is my Registry view (with some light editing):

[image]

and:

[image]

My issue here seems to be the opposite of every other one I've found on Stackoverflow, where one complains about "missing keys", that were in fact under `Wow6432Node`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WOW64 registry redirection mostly applies to keys under HKLM and HKCR. Only COM related keys under HKCU\Software\Classes are redirected/reflected. See MSDN for details: [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253(v=vs.85).aspx).